# How do I fix "An argument of 'series bool' type was used but a 'simple float' is expected" error

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm new to pinescript coding, I'm writing a script for a DCA strategy and I want Signal Oscillator Kalman to make purchases according to the risks when reaching the limits (-100, -80, -60, -40, -20, 0, 20, 40, 60, 80 , 95), but I keep getting some errors.

Here's the code:

```
//@version=5
strategy(
  title                 = "DCA",
  pyramiding            = 500,
  default_qty_type      = strategy.percent_of_equity,
  overlay               = false,
  default_qty_value     = 0,
  initial_capital       = 0) //}

// Inputs { ————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
T_ceiling   = input.string("Off", "Diminishing Returns", ["Off","Linear","Parabolic"], "Account for diminishing returns as time increases")
day         = input.int(1, "Day",1,28,1,"Select day of month for buy orders.")
DCAamount   = input.int(1000,"DCA Amount",400,tooltip="Enter the maximum amount you'd be willing to DCA for any given month.")
T_buy       = input(true,"Buy Orders","Toggle buy orders.")
T_sell      = input(true,"Sell Orders","Toggle sell orders.")

// Libraries
import gotbeatz26107/ma_/2 as ma

// Indicator settings
htfInterval         = input.timeframe("D", title = 'Timeframe', options = ['D', '3D', 'W', '2W', 'M'], 
                                 group = 'Indicator settings', inline = '1')

average_type        = input.string  ("JMA", inline = '1', title = "Moving Average Type", group = 'Indicator settings')

osc_ma_length       = input.int(70, title = "MA length", group = "Indicator settings")

Sharpness           = input.float(35.0, "Sharpness", group = "Kalman Filter", inline = "kf")
K                   = input.float(1.0, "Filter Period", group = "Kalman Filter", inline = "kf")
use_kalman          = input.bool(true, title = "Use kalman filter for signals?", group = "Kalman Filter")

incl_balance        = input.bool(true, group = "Metrics", title = "Mean value")
incl_tx_large       = input.bool(true, group = "Metrics", title = "Transfers")

// Time period
testStartYear   = input.int(2018,   title="Backtest Start Year",    minval=2010,maxval=2100,group="Backtest Period")
testStartMonth  = input.int(1,      title="Backtest Start Month",   minval=1,   maxval=12,  group="Backtest Period")
testStartDay    = input.int(1,      title="Backtest Start Day",     minval=1,   maxval=31,  group="Backtest Period")
testPeriodLen   = input.int(9999,   title="Backtest Period (days)", minval=1,               group="Backtest Period",tooltip="Days until strategy ends") * 86400000 // convert days into UNIX time
testPeriodStart = timestamp(testStartYear,testStartMonth,testStartDay,0,0)
testPeriodStop  = testPeriodStart + testPeriodLen
testPeriod() =>
    time >= testPeriodStart and time <= testPeriodStop ? true : false
// ——————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————— }
// ——————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————— }
// Kalman filter
kalman_filter(src, Sharpness, K) =>
    
    velocity = 0.0
    kfilt = 0.0

    Distance = src - nz(kfilt[1], src)
    Error = nz(kfilt[1], src) + Distance * math.sqrt(Sharpness*K/ 100)
    velocity := nz(velocity[1], 0) + Distance*K / 100
    kfilt := Error + velocity
    kfilt
//

// Function to calculate bollinger bands deviation
bbr(float src, int length) =>

    basis = ma.selector(src, length, average_type)
    dev = 1 * ta.stdev(src, length)

    upper = basis + dev
    lower = basis - dev
    bbr = (src - lower)/(upper - lower)

    //Output
    bbr
//

// Profiler function
profiler(float src, float percentile, int lookback) =>
    poc_val = ta.percentile_linear_interpolation(src, lookback, 50)
    lower_boundary_val = ta.percentile_linear_interpolation(src, lookback, 100 - percentile)
    upper_boundary_val = ta.percentile_linear_interpolation(src, lookback, percentile)
    [poc_val, lower_boundary_val, upper_boundary_val]

//
// Convert Timeframe
getTimeframeMinutes(timeframe) =>

    // Input
    minutes = 0

    // Conversion
    if timeframe == '5'
        minutes := 5
    if timeframe == '10'
        minutes := 10
    if timeframe == '15'
        minutes := 15
    if timeframe == '30'
        minutes := 30
    if timeframe == '60'
        minutes := 60
    if timeframe == '120'
        minutes := 120        
    if timeframe == '240'
        minutes := 240
    if timeframe == '720'
        minutes := 720
    if timeframe == 'D'
        minutes := 1440
    if timeframe == '3D'
        minutes := 4320
    if timeframe == 'W'
        minutes := 10080
    if timeframe == '2W'
        minutes := 20160
    if timeframe == 'M'
        minutes := 43200

    // Output
    minutes
//
calculateTimeframeRatio(htf) =>
    getTimeframeMinutes(htf) / getTimeframeMinutes(timeframe.period)
tf_ratio            = calculateTimeframeRatio(htfInterval) 
//

percentile          = input(99, title = "Value Area Percentile", inline = 'l2', group = "Indicator settings")
lookback            = input(365, title = "Lookback period", inline = 'l2', group = "Indicator settings") * tf_ratio

bound_up            = input(90.0, title = "Upper bound", inline = "b1", group = "Bounds")
bound_dn            = input(-90.0, title = "Lower bound", inline = "b1", group = "Bounds")

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
//----------------------------------------------------Calculation-----------------------------------------------------//
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

// Mean Value
avg_balance         = request.security("INTOTHEBLOCK:" + syminfo.basecurrency + "_AVGTXUSD", htfInterval, close, ignore_invalid_symbol = true)

avg_balance() =>

    avg_balance_30 = ma.selector(math.log(avg_balance), 30 * tf_ratio, average_type)
    avg_balance_90 = ma.selector(math.log(avg_balance), 90 * tf_ratio, average_type)

    // Extract values from the profiler
    [poc_val, lower_boundary_val, upper_boundary_val] = profiler(avg_balance_30, percentile, lookback)

    avg_balance_score = 0

    if avg_balance_30 >= poc_val
        avg_balance_score += 25
    if avg_balance_30 >= upper_boundary_val
        avg_balance_score += 25
    if avg_balance_30 >= avg_balance_90
        avg_balance_score += 25
    if avg_balance_90 >= poc_val
        avg_balance_score += 25

    if avg_balance_30 <= poc_val
        avg_balance_score -= 25
    if avg_balance_30 <= lower_boundary_val
        avg_balance_score -= 25
    if avg_balance_30 <= avg_balance_90
        avg_balance_score -= 25
    if avg_balance_90 <= poc_val
        avg_balance_score -= 25

    // Output
    avg_balance_score
//

// Sum
tx_large_usd        = request.security("COINMETRICS:" + syminfo.basecurrency + "_LARGETXVOLUMEUSD", htfInterval, close, ignore_invalid_symbol = true)

tx_large() =>

    tx_large_30 = ma.selector(math.log(tx_large_usd), 30 * tf_ratio, average_type)
    tx_large_90 = ma.selector(math.log(tx_large_usd), 90 * tf_ratio, average_type)

    [poc_val, lower_boundary_val, upper_boundary_val] = profiler(tx_large_30, percentile, lookback)

    tx_large_score = 0

    if tx_large_30 >= tx_large_90
        tx_large_score += 25
    if tx_large_30 >= poc_val
        tx_large_score += 25
    if tx_large_30 >= upper_boundary_val
        tx_large_score += 25
    if tx_large_90 >= poc_val
        tx_large_score += 25

    if tx_large_30 <= tx_large_90
        tx_large_score -= 25
    if tx_large_30 <= poc_val
        tx_large_score -= 25
    if tx_large_30 <= lower_boundary_val
        tx_large_score -= 25
    if tx_large_90 <= poc_val
        tx_large_score -= 25

    // Output
    tx_large_score
//

balance = 0
balance := incl_balance ? avg_balance() : 0
tx_large_ = 0
tx_large_ := incl_tx_large ? tx_large() : 0 

counter() => 

    count = 0

    if avg_balance() != 0 and incl_balance
        count += 1
    if tx_large() != 0 and incl_tx_large
        count += 1
    // Output
    count
//
count = counter()

fundamental = (balance + tx_large_ ) / count
fundamental_ma = ma.selector(fundamental, osc_ma_length * tf_ratio, average_type)
fundamental_kalman = kalman_filter(fundamental, Sharpness, K)
signal = use_kalman ? fundamental_kalman : fundamental


plot(fundamental_kalman, color = color.orange, title = "Signal Oscillator Kalman")


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

// Risk Levels { ———————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————

kalman = fundamental_kalman

// Risk Lines
price       = close
riskLow     = ta.crossover(kalman,-100)
risk1       = ta.crossover(kalman,-80)
risk2       = ta.crossover(kalman,-60)
risk3       = ta.crossover(kalman,-40)
risk4       = ta.crossover(kalman,-20)
risk5       = ta.crossover(kalman,0)
risk6       = ta.crossover(kalman,20)
risk7       = ta.crossover(kalman,40)
risk8       = ta.crossover(kalman,60)
risk9       = ta.crossover(kalman,80)
riskHigh    = ta.crossover(kalman,95)

// ——————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————— }
// Order Execution { ———————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
line5   = kalman<risk5 and kalman>risk4
line4   = kalman<risk4 and kalman>risk3
line3   = kalman<risk3 and kalman>risk2
line2   = kalman<risk2 and kalman>risk1
line1   = kalman<risk1

// DCA buy order weights
y       = DCAamount / 5
switch
    line5 => y:= y * 1
    line4 => y:= y * 2
    line3 => y:= y * 3
    line2 => y:= y * 4
    line1 => y:= y * 5

// Contracts per order
contracts =(y/price)

if testPeriod()
// Buy orders
    if T_buy == true
        if dayofmonth == day
            strategy.entry("Risk Line 5",strategy.long,qty=contracts,when=line5)
            strategy.entry("Risk Line 4",strategy.long,qty=contracts,when=line4)
            strategy.entry("Risk Line 3",strategy.long,qty=contracts,when=line3)
            strategy.entry("Risk Line 2",strategy.long,qty=contracts,when=line2)
            strategy.entry("Risk Line 1",strategy.long,qty=contracts,when=line1)
// Sell orders 
    if T_sell == true
        if strategy.opentrades > 5
            strategy.exit("Risk Line 6",qty_percent=6.67,limit=risk6) 
            strategy.exit("Risk Line 7",qty_percent=14.28,limit=risk7)
            strategy.exit("Risk Line 8",qty_percent=25.00,limit=risk8)
            strategy.exit("Risk Line 9",qty_percent=44.44,limit=risk9)
            strategy.exit("Risk Line 10",qty_percent=100,limit=riskHigh)
// ——————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————— }
```

And this is the error message I'm getting.

```
Error at 251:18 Cannot call 'operator <' with argument 'expr1'='risk5'. An argument of 'series bool' type was used but a 'simple float' is expected.
Error at 251:35 Cannot call 'operator >' with argument 'expr1'='risk4'. An argument of 'series bool' type was used but a 'simple float' is expected.
Error at 252:18 Cannot call 'operator <' with argument 'expr1'='risk4'. An argument of 'series bool' type was used but a 'simple float' is expected.
Error at 252:35 Cannot call 'operator >' with argument 'expr1'='risk3'. An argument of 'series bool' type was used but a 'simple float' is expected.
Error at 253:18 Cannot call 'operator <' with argument 'expr1'='risk3'. An argument of 'series bool' type was used but a 'simple float' is expected.
Error at 253:35 Cannot call 'operator >' with argument 'expr1'='risk2'. An argument of 'series bool' type was used but a 'simple float' is expected.
Error at 254:18 Cannot call 'operator <' with argument 'expr1'='risk2'. An argument of 'series bool' type was used but a 'simple float' is expected.
Error at 254:35 Cannot call 'operator >' with argument 'expr1'='risk1'. An argument of 'series bool' type was used but a 'simple float' is expected.
Error at 255:18 Cannot call 'operator <' with argument 'expr1'='risk1'. An argument of 'series bool' type was used but a 'simple float' is expected.
Error at 281:64 Cannot call 'strategy.exit' with argument 'limit'='risk6'. An argument of 'series bool' type was used but a 'series float' is expected.
Error at 282:65 Cannot call 'strategy.exit' with argument 'limit'='risk7'. An argument of 'series bool' type was used but a 'series float' is expected.
Error at 283:65 Cannot call 'strategy.exit' with argument 'limit'='risk8'. An argument of 'series bool' type was used but a 'series float' is expected.
Error at 284:65 Cannot call 'strategy.exit' with argument 'limit'='risk9'. An argument of 'series bool' type was used but a 'series float' is expected.
Error at 285:64 Cannot call 'strategy.exit' with argument 'limit'='riskHigh'. An argument of 'series bool' type was used but a 'series float' is expected.
```

Answer (score 0):

`ta.crossover()` returns a `bool`. Your function `kalman_filter()` returns a `float`.

You cannot compare a `bool` with a `float`. That doesn't make sense and that's what the compiler is telling you.